# Use string variable as color

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is have something like this

```
var myVar = "blue"
```

then do

```
document.body.style.color = myVar
```

so the color of body is blue.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: This should be done in CSS. Why are you using JS? (Just curious)

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz what i want to do is be able to use text strings to add parts of hex codes together then use it as one whole hex code, for example,    var myVar =  #2b + 3a + 5d

Comment: Are the hex codes being [randomly](http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/oxyjQV) generated?

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz there will be a mixture of random generation and user input

Comment: I see JS abused a lot because of convenience. So I thought I'd ask why. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 7):

That will work to make the text blue. If you wanted to change the background color use `backgroundColor`

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = myVar;
```